# New List item customisation

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss

I currently have a custom list which contains about 20 columns, however when my user selects new to add in a new item to the list I want to only show 10 of the 20 fields.

The default setting allows me to hide some fields but this option is not what i need as later on in the workflow i require a user to add in data to say items 11-20.

I need a couple of data entry forms

new - show say columns 1-10
update - modify columns 1-10 if required and add data to columns 10-15
authorise - modify columns 1-15 if required and add data to columns 15-20

Ideally each data entry form should have its own workflow but that can come later and is a nice to have

any help please ?

by the way sharepoint designer is not an option for me, I do however have info path available.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a custom list you can define which fields are going to be available on each form using the attributes ShowInDisplayForm, ShowInEditForm and ShowInNewForm.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543225.aspx

I usually use them when im define the content type.

```
<FieldRef ID="{493AE2E2-DA5D-46C6-93D9-D43F85B03329}" Name="myCustomField" Required="FALSE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE"/>
```

i hope it helps!

Comment: great thanks I will go take a look - anticipate my system which is locked down won't allow me to make changes at this level but lets see !!